# Azure - Getting errors in different regions

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-sql-database

When we use the website, no errors occur, however when using a VPN from another region, we get the following error (Entity Framework) when going to a certain page:

> "Invalid column name 'BeginDate'.  Invalid column name 'EndDate'."

The code that the error occurs on is this:

```
public void InsertItem<T>() where T : class
{
    string name = (typeof(T)).Name;
    var item = db.Set<T>().AsNoTracking().ToList();
    Cache.Insert(name, item, null, Expiration, Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
}
```

Specifically, the call to db.Set is where the error occurs.

This started happening after deploying an update to production. Some of our customers, who are in a different region, are seeing this error, but none of our devs are unless we use a VPN.

As far as the error goes, it should be impossible to be getting it. The entity (T) that causes the error doesn't have, and never has had the columns "BeginDate" or "EndDate". The table doesn't either. There's a Navigation Property on T that had those columns, but I believe they were removed two releases ago.

Does anyone know why this could be happening? Thank you.

Comment: do you have any firewall in place for your azure environments that limits the access from different region?

Comment: @ArashEM I don't believe so. They can access the website fine, some features just don't work (adding a product to their cart, for example) due to this error.

Comment: try to debug your environment remotely when using VPN and see what happens.

Comment: @ArashEM It just throws the error I listed in the post

Comment: This sounds like a versioning/deployment issue on one of the regions. You mentioned the navigation properties "BeginDate" and "EndDate"  were removed two releases ago. Something is obviously still referencing them or how would it even know about them.